# Zooming in Iframe effecting the wrong cursor position in cordova iOS application

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css, cordova

I am using Cordova for ios development. I use an iframe to open an external link in my app. The external page size is large and in order to fit into the screen I am using -webkit-transform scale property. Everything is fine and it fits into the screen. But the problem is that when I select a text input, the input cursor (caret) starts blinking somewhere below the text field.

[image: Image1]

---

Please see the code:

index.html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="personDetailPage">
        <div data-role="header" class="header" >
            <div class="logo"  id="mainScreenLogo"> <img src="" id="headerLogoImg" /> </div>
            <h1 id="personDetailTitle"class="tittle">Person Detail</h1>
            <a href="#main" class="ui-btn-right headerHomeIcon"  data-transition="slide" onclick="formHomeButtonClick();"> <img src="homeIcon.png" class="headerHomeImg" /> </a>    
        </div>
        <div id="iFrameDiv" scrolling="no"> 
            <iframe id="formframe" width="280" height="150" src="form.html" onLoad='fixiFrame();' frameborder="0" ></iframe>  
        </div>

    </div>
```

form.html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="personRegistration" scrolling="no"><br>
        Please Enter the Person Details
        <form id="registrationForm" method="POST" action="https://abe.com/Registration.aspx" onsubmit="return checkform();" >
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>

            <a href="" id="my-custom-button-registration" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="return checkform();">Continue</a>
        </form> 
    </div>
```

and JS is:

```
function fixiFrame() { // set the size of IFrame to the device screen fit
    $("#formframe").width( viewport.width  );
    $("#formframe").height( viewport.height -35- deviceVarient );
}

function resizeIframe(){  //zoom the person registration Iframe upto screen fit it will be called when device ready
    var xaix = viewport.width /widthFactor; // widthFactor is the actual page sixe of external page i.e; abc.com/Registration.aspx
    var yaix = (viewport.height-35- $(".logo").height() ) /heightFactor;
    $('#formframe').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale('+xaix+','+yaix+')');
  $('#formframe').css('-webkit-transform-origin', '0 0');


    //alert('resizeIframe(): xaix = '+xaix+' yaix = '+yaix+' $(.logo).height() = '+$(".logo").height()); //for testing & debugging
}
```

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue, it's driving me nuts

Comment: I have given its solution in answer that make me luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an old problem that was also faced by me. I have looked into my two year old code for the solution of this problem and here is the solution.

Instead of using the **`iframe`** for opening the external link, that would be embedded in another page, I had used the **`inAppBrowser`** for this for opening external link.

**`window.open( encodeURI('externalPage.html') , '_blank', 'location=no','EnableViewPortScale=yes');`**

Now, what **'EnableViewPortScale=yes'** option do. Its set the `browserOptions.enableviewportscale` to `true` in **`CDVInAppBrowser.m`** that was used in **`openInInAppBrowser`** method in same class for `UIWebView` `options` . i.e;

```
self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView.scalesPageToFit = browserOptions.enableviewportscale;
```

it means the above line is replace to;

**`self.inAppBrowserViewController.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;`**

**`UIWebView`** is actually have a property **`scalesPageToFit`** that fits the page to the device width considering the aspect ratio.

Comment: I would prefer a JS/CSS solution, but we'll have to give this a try

Comment: This is JS solution. Just use **'EnableViewPortScale=yes'** option for width fit. 


`window.open( encodeURI('externalPage.html') , '_blank', 'location=no','EnableViewPortScale=yes'); `

Here is alternative solution.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702313/cordova-inappbrowser-doesnt-scale-the-page-loaded`

Comment: The App should work as a webapp too, so using a Cordova plugin instead of an iframe is not an option

Comment: I've given you the bounty anyway. Thanks for your help!